# C# program freezes using stopwatch to time an action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows form program which controls a light. This light has its own class. I can do things like turn it on an off and change the color etc. This I can do without issue. What I want to be able to do, however, is make the light go on for a specific amount of time, i.e. 100 milliseconds or 300 milliseconds (depending on use).

I have tried to used stopwatch to do this, but when I click on the button that is meant to do this, it freezes the program. The light goes on, then doesn't turn off, and I can't use the stop button I have which is meant to turn it off.

The program loads the light, and initialises it, and displays an alert saying it has done this and detected one light. Then I use this:

```
   private void Red_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Displays Red

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)delegate()
        {
            displayRedDot();
        });
     }
```

This is the displayRedDot()

```
public void displayRedDot()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch clock1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        long elapsedTime = clock1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        clock1.Start();
        while (elapsedTime < 100)
        {
            oBlynclightController.Display(BlynclightController.Color.Red);
        }
        oBlynclightController.Display(BlynclightController.Color.Off);
        clock1.Stop();


    }
```

I have some other functions, which are identical this with a different time, which I haven't invoked anywhere yet because I can't get this to work.

Comment: Why did you tag the question as  Asp.Net?

Comment: Aside from LB's answer try investigating BackgroundWorker Class. It's a good way to start learning thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will never work since you are blocking the UI thread  by busy waiting. This is the reason for your program seems to freeze. Use a timer or  async/await instead

```
async  void DisplayRedDot(int duration)
{
    oBlynclightController.Display(BlynclightController.Color.Red);
    await Task.Delay(duration);
    oBlynclightController.Display(BlynclightController.Color.Off);
}
```

Comment: THink this is the answer. I'm also thinking that he is blocking the UI thread thats why it freezes.

Answer (score 5):

`elapsedTime` will never change its value. You initialize it right after creating the stopwatch, but never assign a new value to it. `Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` is a `long`. `long` is a value type.  A copy is created and assigned to `elapsedTime`.  You need:

```
while (clock1.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100)
{
    oBlynclightController.Display(BlynclightController.Color.Red);
}
```

Note that this loop is going to run very quickly until that check returns false. Is this really what you want?  I don't know exactly what your code is doing (you don't show us), but why not just set the color to red, wait 100ms, and then set it to... erm, `Off`.

It's also difficult for humans to pick up a change that only lasts 100ms. It's going to be a flicker at best.

Comment: Technically it is going to possibly be 1 frame. doing that often is going to require health warnings as it may trigger seizures. Bad architecture - the program as written makes no sense at all. It also all happens on the UI Thread, so - bad news: no trigger, the control never redraws as this only happens once the function has ended and the UI Thread processes the redraws ;)

Comment: Well, if it is not run on the UI Thread then it can not change the properties of controls and would have to invoke back into the UI Thread, which it does not do. Unless it runs REALLY old .NET code it should run an exception somewhere when it sets a property then.

Comment: @TomTom: Yeah, I don't know what `oBlynclightController.Display` is doing, but this code is no good.  I upvoted L.B.'s response, much better